# Solving Titanic(Kaggle) Dataset using RFC, Unknown label type: 'unknown'

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I am solving the Titanic Kaggle Dataset using RFC and I am getting an error saying 'Unknown label type: 'unknown'' while fitting the data to the model. I feel the error is in y, but I couldn't find anything.

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
data = data.fillna(data.mean())
data = data.replace('male',1)
data = data.replace('female',0)
data = data.replace('S',0)
data = data.replace('C',1)
data = data.replace('Q',2)
data['Embarked'] = data['Embarked'].fillna('S')
data = data[data.Embarked != 'S']
y = data.Survived
np.unique(y)
features = ['Pclass','Sex','Age','Fare','SibSp','Parch','Embarked']
X = data[features]
trainX,trainY,valX,valY = train_test_split(X,y,random_state = 1)  
titanmodel = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 1)
titanmodel.fit(trainX,trainY)
```

The model fitting part with the error
    ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
Also, if you have any better tips of approaching this, please do tell.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The feature cabin has missing values too. See https://www.kaggle.com/jirakst/titanic-auc-90 for the whole solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of [train_test_split()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) is X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test and you are assigning values in a different order in your code.

Change the line:

```
trainX,trainY,valX,valY = train_test_split(X,y,random_state = 1)
```

By this one:

```
trainX,valX,trainY,valY = train_test_split(X,y,random_state = 1)
```

and you will be able to fit the model with the correct parameters.

Comment: Thanks a tonne! Such a random mistake!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you. Please accept my answer and upvote it if you think that it worths it! @Crossfit_Jesus